# phvr7t cannot be found despite having installed psnfss

Tags: fonts, texlive, mactex

I wish to use the Helvetica package. I installed the `psnfss` package with tlmgr (and in a fit of desperation other font-related packages, such as `times` and `ae`). However, I still do not have any `phvr7t` files in my texlive distribution. I do have `phvr8g.tfm`, `phvro8g.tfm`, `phvr8gn.tfm` and `phvro8gn.tfm` at `/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/metapost/`, if that helps.

I used the Mactex texlive-2012-basic installer.

EDIT: I manually installed `psnfss`, because tlmgr did not copy any font files into the texmf distro. I now have `phvr7t.tfm` and `phvr7t.vf` at `/texmf/fonts`, but Latex can't seem to find them.

Comment: Why did you install manually? This seems to contradict the earlier statement that you used `tlmgr`: which is it?

Comment: Edited to be clearer. tlmgr did not seem to actually copy any font files into the /texmf tree, so I had to manually install psnfss.

Comment: You should always add a small but complete example so that other can test if it is a general problem or something specific to your installation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free Helvetica font, I suggest you use the Heros font (with the `tgheros` package) from the [TeX Gyre](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) collection instead of the GhostScript fonts, since the GhostScript fonts [recently were reverted to their original versions by URW](http://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2011-March/008939.html) and the TeX Gyre fonts are highly improved (many more glyphs, improved lettershapes, adapted to Open Type technology) versions of these fonts.

Answer (score 0):

In adding an MWE, I found that the `helvet` package must be on its own `\usepackage` command. That is, my problem was the line `\usepackage{natbib,caption,fancyhdr,helvet}`.

Comment: The number of packages in `\usepackage` should not matter. But the order of packages _may_ matter. Hard to say without an MWE...

Answer (score 0):

Install package `helvetic` for `phvr7t.tfm` using `TeX Live Utility`.
You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/)